# Scraping Restaurant Details from Trip Advisor

Tags: python, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a script to scrap Restaurant details from TripAdvisor site. Just for learning.

The problem here is I cant find restaurant names in Source page from the second page. Well, actually there is no correct second link. But when I check live site and inspect, I can see the restaurant name.

For Eg:

```
https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g294003-Kuwait_City.html
```

In the above link, te first link, I can get all the source correctly. But when I select 2,3 or Other Links from bottom, I cant able to view page source correctly. It is displaying the same source of first one.

My current Code

```
import urllib.request
import requests #Install certifi for https
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.tripadvisor.in/Restaurants-g294003-Kuwait_City.html"
r=requests.get(url)
data=r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"lxml")

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
print ("\n\n\n\n\n\n")

url1 = "https://www.tripadvisor.in/RestaurantSearch-g294003-oa120-Kuwait_City.html"
r=requests.get(url)
data=r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"lxml")
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

I am Stuck here. Dont know what to do .

Answer (score 1):

I think you had a typo in the second part of your code:

```
url1 = "https://www.tripadvisor.in/RestaurantSearch-g294003-oa120-Kuwait_City.html"

r=requests.get(url)

#Change this to:
r=requests.get(url1)
```

Comment: Thank you . It was just a sample Link. How to get those all links in the bottom. ?

Comment: If you meant the page numbers below, you will observe that they have the following pattern: /Restaurants-g294003-oa30-Kuwait_City.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS
   Increase oa30 to oa60, oa90 ..and so on till the last page oa480

Comment: Try: for div in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class':'pageNum taLnk'}):
    print(div.get('href'))